# Problems with SSH when router is reset

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have set up port forward on my home router, so that I can SSH from anywhere to my desktop using the router's public ip.  However, it appears that anytime the router looses power, this public ip changes, and I need to look up the new one before I can SSH again (which requires being on my home network).  This wouldn't be a big deal, except that I am going out of town for the summer and want to be able to connect to my home desktop without worrying about the ip reseting if there is a power outage.

What is the *simplest* solution to this problem (I am pretty new to all this stuff, a lot of suggestions I've found are over my head).  If it is important, I am using Ubuntu on both ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your router. Many routers support dynamic dns providers.  Routers supporting dynamic dns notify your dns provider every time your public ip address changes. You don't need to know the public ip any more. You do only use the dns entry.

Comment: Usually, I do something like 'ssh user@publicip'.  How would I do things differently if I want to use the "dns entry" instead of the ip?  Is there something that needs to set up in order for this to work?

Comment: You have to look up the documentation of your router if it supports dynamic dns and how to setup it. It''s vendor specific.

Comment: It appears that my router only allows dynamic dns through dyndns.com.  That is a paid service and I am looking for something free.  Are there alternatives to the dns solution?

Comment: You can try out ddclient or similar program's. If it is not a solution and you own a Webserver you can setup a cron job with curl or wget. This way you find your public ip within your Webserver logs.

Comment: I wound up just paying for a dyndns.com account, since it wasn't too expensive and it was the simplest option.  Thanks for the help!